# Issues with checkout process in cartridge

Tags: django, checkout, payment-processing, mezzanine, cartridge

I am using **mezzanine + cartridge** for a shopping cart.I want to use the concept of *reward points(like discount coupon)* in it and users who have enough reward points so that they can pay through them and want to use them then at checkout time the payment details step must be *disabled* for these users and order is placed.

So I just want to know how I can disable this payment step in cartridge. Anybody who have used cartridge in their projects  can tell me it is **feasible or not.** and if yes then HOW ?

There is one module of discount coupon in cartridge but it does not fulfil my requirements so I am not using this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is completely feasible. Cartridge is just a Django application.

Is there a one-to-one ratio of reward points to your local currency?

I might start by extending the Account model with a cartridge.shop.fields.MoneyField called "reward_points". Next, add the necessary fields and logic to a customized version of [cartridge.shop.forms.OrderForm](https://github.com/stephenmcd/cartridge/blob/master/cartridge/shop/forms.py#L270-L400).

Your best option for getting timely and accurate answers to questions about Mezzanine and Cartridge are the [#mezzanine](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/irc/) channel on Freenode and the [mezzanine-users](http://groups.google.com/group/mezzanine-users) Google Groups mailing list.